# removing nonwords from a text without any library

Tags: python

How to remove nonwords from this without using any library in python?

By a word I mean strings containing only the English letters plus ”’” and ”-”.
Hence, we consider words like ”can’t”, ”John’s”, and ”full-time” as valid words.
Furthermore, a word doesn’t contain any digits, or symbols like ”.”, ”,”, ”!”, ”?”, etc.
The only single-letter words in English are ”a” and ”I”

```
99998   Zwizwai confirmed that there were attempts to place him, together with Mudzuri, on the 
sanctions list, describing them as “a Nicodimous diploآکروجت تاج طلایی نیروی هوایی شاهنشاهی ایران ” by 
some fellow MDC-T 
    ______________________________________
    |                                      |
    |  The Cast: (in order of appearance)  |
    |______________________________________|
100000   在大會上，女神為女性安全再次發聲，代表"HeforShe"運動發表消除校園暴力，保障女性安全（calling 
on universities to ensure the safety of women on campus）的演講。
```

this what i tried

```
for word in row.split():
    
    if word.isalpha() == False:
        word = word[:-1]
    
    print (word)
    words.append(word.lower())

return words
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
words = list()
with open("file.txt", errors="ignore") as infile:
    for row in infile:
        for word in row.split():
            if word.strip('"(.,!?):').replace("'","").replace("-","").isalpha():
                words.append(word.strip('"(.,!?):').lower())

>>> " ".join(words)
'zwizwai confirmed that there were attempts to place him together with mudzuri on the sanctions list describing them as nicodimous by some fellow mdc-t the cast in order of appearance on universities to ensure the safety of women on'
```

Comment: thank for you help that work but  still their these کروجت تاج طلایی نیروی هوایی شاهنشاهی

Comment: I don't get that in the output. Using `isalpha` filters out non-Latin characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for word in row.split():
    word = word.replace("!", "").replace("?", "").replace(".", "") # since they are included in a word if it's splitted by spaces
    if word.replace("'", "").replace("-", "").isalpha():
        words.append(word.lower())
```